# How to access ESP8266 using domain name

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I want to map my domain to my ESP8266 server is there any way to do that? I think blynk app is doing that.

Comment: Your domain registrar has instructions on how to add records to your domain. That would be the logical place to start.

Comment: https://github.com/ayushsharma82/EasyDDNS